# Simplify this regular expression to avoid repetition of a term

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript, how would you simplify this regular expression? I would like not to repeat ae.

```
\.ae\.|^ae\.
```

This should match

```
www.ae.com
ae.com
ae.co.uk
test.ae.com
```

but not match

```
asdfgrae.com
aedfr.com
```

Comment: Should it match `example.com` or not, i.e. when no `ae` at all is in the string?

Comment: Have you considered `\bae\b`?

Comment: @Bergi it should not match example.com

Comment: @NPE this is quite interesting, what is a word boundary?

Comment: It is more general than a dot, so may or may not work for your exact use case. There's plenty of resources on the net, see for example http://javascript.info/tutorial/word-boundary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use alternation in a group to match either a `.` or at the start of the string:

```
(?:\.|^)ae\.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can factor the `ae\.`:

```
(?:^|\.)ae\.
```

`(?:...)` is a non capturing group.